# Displaying Intel Galileo IP address on a 16x2 LCD

Tags: intel-galileo, windowsondevices, iot

I'm running the 16x2 LCD sample from Windows Developer Program for IoT (https://ms-iot.github.io/content/16x2LCD.htm). What's the best way do get and show the Galileo IP address on the display instead of "Hello!" message? Regards.

Code

stdafx.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "arduino.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal.h" // we need this library for the LCD commands
```

Main.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

int RS = 4;
int ENABLE = 5;
int D0 = 6;
int D1 = 7;
int D2 = 8;
int D3 = 9;
LiquidCrystal lcd = LiquidCrystal(RS, ENABLE, D0, D1, D2, D3); // define our LCD and which pins to use

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
    return RunArduinoSketch();
}

void setup()
{
    Log(L"LCD Sample\n");

    lcd.begin(16, 2); // need to specify how many columns and rows are in the LCD unit (it calls clear at the end of begin)

    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Hello!");

    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(3.14159, 4); // prints a double, the 2nd number is the digits to print after the .
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Windows APIs to get the IP address in string form and then use lcd.print to print the string to the LCD.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366314(v=vs.85).aspx) does a good job of explaining and showing how to use the Windows APIs to get the IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

The [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN gives example code for obtaining the IP address. I essentially added the code below to the setup function of a Galileo project and displayed the IP address on a LCD:

```
lcd.begin(16, 2); // columns and rows, LCD unit (it calls clear at the end of begin)
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

lcd.print("IP Address:");

PIP_ADAPTER_INFO    pAdapterInfo = NULL;
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO    pAdapter = NULL;
ULONG               ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
DWORD               dwRetVal = 0;

pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)MALLOC(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
}

if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
    FREE(pAdapterInfo);
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)MALLOC(ulOutBufLen);
    if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
    }
}

if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {
    pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);
}
```

I wrote a blog [post](http://sixfortyfour.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/displaying-intel-galileo-ip-address-on-a-16x2-lcd) that shows the approach I took to get it working. Hope this helps.